# Setting global batch number

Tags: batch

I have a process that from time to time sends me that fail message.

"Maximum number of duplicate updates in one batch (12 allowed). Attempt to update Id more than once in this Api call"

**Is there a way to set the batch number when executing actions from a process are executed.** So that I set them to lower than 12 so that prevent that error.

It happens because the record are generated automatically and then the action is executed too.

I know that it is better to make my processes better. And probably that is exacly what I will do but still it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying there's too many references to the same record. You can't adjust this number, you need to optimize your code so that you don't have duplicate records in the list. Usually, this means using a Map so that you only update each record once.